# Unable to extend partition even though unallocated space is next to it using GParted

Tags: partition, virtualbox

I am running High Sierra in a VM through VirtualBox. I recently increased the size of my vdi and in order for my VM to make use of the increase, I tried to use GParted to extend my partition size. However, this is not working. [image]
[image]

The second picture is when I moved the sda3 partition over to the right so that I could extend my sda2 partition. It does not allow me to resize sda2 to anything larger than the current size. Why am I not able to use the unallocated space to extend sda2?

[image]

Tried committing the move for sda3 but it won't let me and I get an error.
[image: Tried committing the move of sda3 but get an error]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it‘s not about using Apple products as described in the FAQ

Comment: Where is more appropriate?

Comment: That‘s Linux, right? I can migrate it to Unix&Linux for you

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to use the un-allocated space? What error or warning did you get? For us to get a clearer picture of how your partitions are laid out, post a screenshot of running `fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Added the screenshot with the details. I don't get any warning or errors. I'm just unable to drag sda2 to make use of the unallocated space next to it. I can't resize it by typing in the size either.

Comment: Maybe try committing the move of sda3 and then try right clicking and resizing sda2, I think I've had similar troubles with certain operations

Comment: @tenCupMaximum I tried to do that but I get an error. Posted screenshot above.

Comment: I'm not well versed in the MacOS recovery partition, but as a general rule, changing the start offset of a partition containing a filesystem causes the filesystem to fail; Because the filesystem data structures refer to offsets which no longer correct. In other words, moving the filesystem required re-writing it, in many cases. Have you tried performing the resize using MacOS's Disk Utility?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with Disk Utility. It doesn't work. I guess I have create a new VM with the increased disk size.

Comment: @jumpman I meant move it to the left, I think, like move to the left and then expand rightwards, dk if that will help